# Difference between Virtual Address vs physical address

Tags: memory, memory-management

what is the meant by the statement "A computer system supports 32-bit virtual addresses as well as 32-bit physical addresses " , its confusing. I know there is memory management unit(MMU) which does the converstion of virtual address to physical but i am not able to understand what does that statement actually mean?
Please help !!!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell this phrase means: only 4G of physical RAM is supported by hardware and each process can have 4G of virtual memory (so sum across all processes > 4G). Virtual memory will consist of some amount of physical RAM and some amount of swap file.

Comment: what if machine has 80 GB HDD and sum of all processes exceeds HDD space as virtual memory resides in HDD , what type of error it will generate ?

Comment: it depends on particular operating system, but in general if either virtual space of particular process is exhausted (i.e. particular process allocates more than 4G) or all pages from both RAM and page file assigned to some process (i.e. no free page) you'll get some kind of out of memory error (e.g. std::bad_alloc in c++) and mostly the error will be the same for both kind of situations.

Comment: one more note. you should consider only requested memory. e.g. if there are 2 processes and computer has only 2G of RAM and 2G of paging file - processes won't see out of memory error until they require 4G of virtual memory in sum. So, first process allocate 2G of virtual memory and second process allocates 1.9G - everything is OK, but when one of them allocate another 0.1+ G - out of memory error will be thrown.

Comment: Also note that this is very simplified explanation, to get full picture of memory management by modern OS, I'd recommend you to read some good book on this (e.g. http://www.amazon.com/Understanding-Linux-Kernel-Third-Edition/dp/0596005652/ref=cm_lmf_tit_2)